# How to select the vue js el using CSS attribute selector?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this HTML:

```
<div data-identifier='app'>
   ...
</div>
```

And I have this Vue js code:

```
      var app = new Vue({
            el: '[data-identifier]',
            data: {
                
            },
            methods: {

            }
        });
```

But it seems that Vue does not understand `[data-identifier]` CSS selector.

How can I use attribute CSS selector with Vue js?

Answer (score 1):

It should work as shown below:

```js
  var app = new Vue({
            el: '[data-identifier]',
            data: {
              msg:"hello" 
            },
            methods: {

            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div data-identifier='app'>
   {{msg}}
</div>
```